# How to move shapes from its new instance by requestAnimationFrame?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, html5-canvas, html5-animation

Here is the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nf7koqpn/).
Small rectangle will be created to simulate a bullet when the spacebar(keycode 32) is pressed. I encountered some problems: How to move them yo the top (decrease the y coordinate)?
Can anyone help me? Thx!

```
window.requestAnimationFrame = window.requestAnimationFrame || window.mozRequestAnimationFrame || window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame || window.msRequestAnimationFrame;
var canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
var cw = canvas.width;
var ch = canvas.height;
var ps = false;

init();

function init(){
    context.rect((cw-5)/2, ch-5, 5, 5);
  context.fill();
  update();
}

function update(){
  if(ps){
    playerShoot();
  }
  requestAnimationFrame(update);
}

function playerShoot(){
    var b = new bullet(2);
}

function bullet(speed){
    this.speed = speed;
  speed++;
  context.ellipse((cw-1)/2, ch-10-speed, 1, 3, 0, 0, Math.PI*2);
  context.fill();
}

document.addEventListener("keydown", function(e){
  switch(e.keyCode){
    case 32:
        ps = true;
      break;
  };
});

document.addEventListener("keyup", function(e){
  switch(e.keyCode){
    case 32:
        ps = false;
      break;
  };
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I've explained a lot of the code in the comments in the code itself.

A couple of other points:

- Some browsers (including mine, i.e. Firefox v44.0.2) don't draw ellipses. So I've made your bullet another rectangle.
- I used `fillRect` instead of `rect` just because I know that better.
- I redrew the bullet by drawing over the old one with the opaque background color. However, you could also clear the rectangle around the previous bullet if you wanted.
- You incremented speed in your example. That's probably not what you want from a conceptual point of view, even if you had gotten the visual results that you want. I suspect you want your bullets to move at a constant speed. Therefore, the `speed` variable should be constant, i.e. not change. Rather, you should use the `speed` constant to regularly change the position of the bullet. I changed `bulletY`, which is the vertical position of the bullet.
- For simplicity, I've only allowed one bullet on the screen at a time.
- I've limited the code to running 500 cycles. That's mostly to just not annoy Stack Overflow users who try the code...they don't want an infinite loop happening.

```js
window.requestAnimationFrame = window.requestAnimationFrame || window.mozRequestAnimationFrame || window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame || window.msRequestAnimationFrame;
var canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
var cw = canvas.width;
var ch = canvas.height;
var ps = false;

// some new variables
var bulletShowing = false; // is a bullet currently showing?
var bulletY; // the vertical position of the bullet
var speed = 8; // the bullet speed
var time = 500; // the time remaining

init();

function init() {
  
  // draw background
  context.fillStyle = "yellow";
  context.fillRect(0, 0, cw, ch);
  
  // draw gun
  context.fillStyle = "black";
  context.fillRect((cw - 5) / 2, ch - 5, 5, 5);

  // update the scene
  update();
}

function update() {
  if (ps) {
    playerShoot();
  }
  
  // if a bullet is supposed to be showing then, well, show it
  if (bulletShowing) {
    
    // redraw the bullet (erase the old, draw the new)
    drawBullet();
    
    // if the bullet has gone off-screen, allow a new shot
    if (bulletY < -5) {
      bulletShowing = false;
    }
  }
  
  // give a visual indicator of time remaining
  document.querySelector("div").innerHTML = "Time: " + time;
  
  // decrement the time
  time -= 1;
  
  // if there is still time remaining, do it all again
  if (time >= 0) {
    requestAnimationFrame(update);
  }
}

function playerShoot() {

  // indicate a bullet will now be showing
  bulletShowing = true;

  // start the bullet out near the gun
  bulletY = ch - 10;
}

function drawBullet() {
  
  // erase the old bullet by drawing over it with the background color
  // this rectangle is slightly larger than the bullet itself
  // to ensure the entire old bullet is drawn over
  context.fillStyle = "yellow";
  context.fillRect((cw - 1) / 2 - 2, bulletY - 1, 5, 7);
  
  // move the bullet position
  bulletY -= speed;
  
  // draw the new bullet
  context.fillStyle = "black";
  context.fillRect((cw - 1) / 2 - 1, bulletY, 3, 5);
}

document.addEventListener("keydown", function(e) {
  switch (e.keyCode) {
    case 32:
      
      // only allow one bullet on the screen at a time
      // (for the sake of coding simplicity)
      if (!bulletShowing) {
        ps = true;
      }
      break;
  };
});

document.addEventListener("keyup", function(e) {
  switch (e.keyCode) {
    case 32:
      ps = false;
      break;
  };
});
```

```css
#myCanvas {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, 5%);
  background-color: #cccccc;
  z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<p>Click on the canvas, then use the space bar to fire bullets one at a time.</p>
<div></div>
<canvas id="myCanvas" width=300 height=150></canvas>
```